# Bad or no connection

Tags: wireless-networking

I have 2 uses of my Internet: I have a laptop and a base station.

I made a stupid decision and accidentally unplugged my base station before shutting it down; I recently changed rooms, but they weren't that far away.

Now my base station is getting 1-2 bars of Internet or sometimes none at all. I can’t connect to the Internet most times, and I have to get really lucky. I have a laptop in the same exact place as my base station, so I know that the router is not the problem in this case.

I have tried almost everything on my Windows 10 base station, and so has my dad. We are trying something now, but if it doesn’t work then were almost out of luck. I don’t understand what is going on. Can anyone leave a suggestion?
                                                                               EDIT:
I have been doing some research online, and apparently it has something to do with Windows 10. It says that firewall is the problem or bitdefender but it's not. I still, do not know much on the subject and i'm really hoping to get an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: I will explain what I learned from your post. “Base-station” is a PC that has wireless connectivity and not a stand-alone wireless AP or some sort of thing. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Not shutting down a PC/Laptop would very rarely affect your hardware. So I suspect that it’s either:

1. Misplaced wireless antenna for the PC.
2. Not installing the antenna at all.
3. The “base station” has less reception power than your laptop.

Note that “not far” and “different room” have a **huge** amount of difference. Since walls have higher ability to attenuate the signal.

Comment: I think the person that downvoted this answer was needlessly harsh - There is a reasonable answer based on the most likely cause of the problem - ie its a distance from the router thing.

Comment: Another thing which can be tried to fix the problem is to change channels.  It may be that the new location has visibility of other access points which are drowning out the signal from the desired Access Point.

Comment: well sorry, but i thought the one asking is by no mean a technical person that understand what a channel is, since he mentioned base station (probably desktop since the reception is compared to a laptop)